# Could not find the ancestor for consumer provider or provider could not be found

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a multi provider config and I pass the providers in the mainApp and using the consumerProvider later. But I get the ancestor not found error. The same setup is working for another view but creating problems maybe because of the navigation

I have tried out some options that I found for similar problems in stackoverflow which stated moving the providers across and also looking at the context that is provided but did not find any solutions

First is my Provider.dart file

```
List<SingleChildCloneableWidget> providers = [
  ...independentServices,
  ...dependentServices,
];

List<SingleChildCloneableWidget> independentServices = [
  Provider.value(value: FirebaseNewsService()),
  Provider.value(value: FirebaseEventsService())
];

List<SingleChildCloneableWidget> dependentServices = [
  ProxyProvider<FirebaseNewsService, NewsListModel>(
      builder: (context, newsService, _) {
    return NewsListModel(newsService: newsService);
  }),
  ProxyProvider<FirebaseNewsService, NewsCreateModel>(
    builder: (context, newsService, _) {
      return NewsCreateModel(newsService: newsService);
    },
  ),
  ProxyProvider<FirebaseEventsService, EventsListModel>(
      builder: (context, eventsService, _) {
    return EventsListModel(eventsService: eventsService);
  }),
];
```

Next is the main.dart file

```
class MainApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
        providers: providers,
          child:MaterialApp(
        title: 'MyApp',
        initialRoute: RoutePaths.Home,
        onGenerateRoute: Router.generateRoute, )
    );
  }
}
```

Next is the router.dart file where routing happens

```
class Router {
  static Route<dynamic> generateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    switch (settings.name) {

// this is working
      case RoutePaths.Home:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
          NewsListModel model = Provider.of(context);
          return ChangeNotifierProvider<NewsListModel>.value(
              value: model, child: NewsPage());
        });
        break;

      case RoutePaths.Events:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) {
EventListModel model = Provider.of(context);
          return ChangeNotifierProvider<EventListModel>.value(
              value: model, child: EventsListPage());
        });
        break;
```

My homepage file

```
class NewsPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String _tab1title = allTranslations.text('newsPage.tabtitleone');
  final String _tab2title = allTranslations.text('newsPage.tabtitletwo');
  static const _tablength = 2;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: _tablength,
      child: Scaffold(
        drawer: Menu(),   //Maybe Menu is having a different context
        body: NestedScrollView(
        ...
        body: Tabbarview(children: [] . // this works fine
```

In the problem widget the Events List .dart file

```
class EventListPage extends statelessWidget {
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    EventListModel model = Provider.of(context);

    return  Scaffold(drawer: Menu(), appBar: AppBar(), body: ChangeNotifierProvider<EventsListModel>.value(
      value: model,
      child: Consumer<EventsListModel>(
        builder: (context, model, child) => model.busy
            ? Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              )
            : Column(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max, children: <Widget>[
                SmartRefresher(
                    //key: EventsPageModel.eventsFollowKey,
                    controller: model.refreshController,
                    enablePullDown: true,
                    header: WaterDropMaterialHeader(
                      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                    ),
                    enablePullUp: true,
                    onRefresh: model.onRefresh,
                    onLoading: model.onLoading,
                    child: buildchild(model, context)),
              ]),
      ),
    );
}
```

I always get could not find ancestor of consumer or
could not find the correct provider .Where I am doing it wrong.

the same thing works for the NewsListModel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was a case sensitive import bug https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21736 .closing this question